# Adding a column stating the worksheet source of the data

Tags: excel, vba

The program's main function is to copy all the data in the worksheets opened and put it in a worksheet named "consolidated." Everything's working well, however, I want to add a column called "Data Source" wherein it can state where the data came from (e.g. Sheet1, Sheet2). But the thing is, it outputs the wrong sheet name.

I have tried different codes and I have attached what currently works below. I will highlight the part where I assume the problem comes from. I would really appreciate some help as I'm not a coder myself (just learned this a week ago).

```
  For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

       'Skip Destination worksheet
        If wksSrc.Name <> wksDst.Name And wksSrc.Name <> "Tool" Then
            With wksSrc

                'Identify the last row and column on this sheet
                'so we know when to stop looping through the data
                lngLastSrcRowNum = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)
                lngLastSrcColNum = LastOccupiedColNum(wksSrc)

                'Identify the last row of the Destination sheet
                'so we know where to (eventually) paste the data
                lngLastDstRowNum = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)

                'Loop through the headers on this sheet, looking up
                'the appropriate Destination column from the Final
                'Headers dictionary and creating ranges on the fly

                For lngIdx = 1 To lngLastSrcColNum

                    strColHeader = Trim(CStr(.Cells(1, lngIdx)))

                    'Set the Destination target range using the
                    'looked up value from the Final Headers dictionary
                    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngLastDstRowNum + 1, _
                                              dicFinalHeaders(strColHeader))

                    'Set the source target range using the current
                    'column number and the last-occupied row
                    Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, lngIdx), _
                                        .Cells(lngLastSrcRowNum, lngIdx))

                    'Copy the data from this sheet to the destination
                    rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst

                Next lngIdx

                Dim TargetColumn As Long
                Dim FinalRow As Long
                Dim rngAddress As Range
                Dim i As Long


                With wksDst
                    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Set rngAddress = .Range("A:Z").Find("Data Source")

                     If Not rngAddress Is Nothing Then
                        TargetColumn = rngAddress.Column 

           ''''THIS IS THE PART WHERE I ASSUME THE PROBLEM COMES FROM'''''
                            For i = 1 To FinalRow
                            .Cells(i, TargetColumn).Value = wksSrc.Name
                            Next i

                     End If

                 End With

            End With
        End If

    Next wksSrc

End Sub
```

I already added the "Data Source" column but the wksSrc.Name part in the code always outputs only the last worksheet name when it should be different/dynamic depending on the worksheets where I got the data from.

This might help. When I make the i value to 1, it outputs the correct sheet name, however, it replaces the column header with the sheet name and the loop is only done once. When I make the i value to 2, it outputs the wrong sheet name but it starts to output in the correct first blank row of the Data Source column.

Comment: a) What happens if you store `wksSrc.Name` to a string variable in the beginning and then assign the string? b) I wouldn't use a `For` loop to assign the value, instead I would set the `Range` to the value (more efficient and faster)

Comment: @Dean - a) I tried it and it still inputs the last sheet name, sadly. 
b) I'm not quite good at understanding Range so I used a For loop to do it (probably the reason why I'm having trouble with this in the first place). The Data Source column is not fixed so I don't know how to reference it.

Comment: Something like this: `.Range(.Cells(1, TargetColumn), .Cells(FinalRow, TargetColumn)).Value = wksSrc.Name` to replace your `For` loop

Comment: Okay figured it out. You are looping through the ENTIRE column each time at the end of the each worksheet. That is why at the end of the process you are left with only the last worksheet name.

Comment: You need to adjust your `FinalRow` for the data you have added PER sheet. You will also need to introduce a `StartRow`. Will send an answer across now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. You are looping through the ENTIRE source name column each time. As such, at the end of your process you will be left with the last worksheet looped through. So in order to overcome this you need a `StartRow` as well as a `FinalRow` to only loop through data from that sheet. See below code (not tested) but I think you will get the idea of how to implement and it may work off the bat.

```vb
For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

       'Skip Destination worksheet
        If wksSrc.Name <> wksDst.Name And wksSrc.Name <> "Tool" Then
            With wksSrc

                'Identify the last row and column on this sheet
                'so we know when to stop looping through the data
                lngLastSrcRowNum = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)
                lngLastSrcColNum = LastOccupiedColNum(wksSrc)

                'Identify the last row of the Destination sheet
                'so we know where to (eventually) paste the data
                lngLastDstRowNum = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)

                'Loop through the headers on this sheet, looking up
                'the appropriate Destination column from the Final
                'Headers dictionary and creating ranges on the fly

                For lngIdx = 1 To lngLastSrcColNum

                    strColHeader = Trim(CStr(.Cells(1, lngIdx)))

                    'Set the Destination target range using the
                    'looked up value from the Final Headers dictionary
                    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngLastDstRowNum + 1, _
                                              dicFinalHeaders(strColHeader))

                    'Set the source target range using the current
                    'column number and the last-occupied row
                    Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, lngIdx), _
                                        .Cells(lngLastSrcRowNum, lngIdx))

                    'Copy the data from this sheet to the destination
                    rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst

                Next lngIdx

                Dim TargetColumn As Long
                Dim FinalRow As Long, StartRow As Long
                Dim rngAddress As Range
                Dim i As Long


                With wksDst

                    Set rngAddress = .Range("A:Z").Find("Data Source")

                     If Not rngAddress Is Nothing Then
                        TargetColumn = rngAddress.Column
                        'set the start for this sheet
                        StartRow = lngLastDstRowNum + 1
                        'set the final row for this worksheet
                        FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                        .Range(.Cells(StartRow, TargetColumn), .Cells(FinalRow, TargetColumn)).Value = wksSrc.Name
                     End If

                 End With

            End With
        End If

    Next wksSrc
```

As can be seen your range adjustment on the `wksDst` should take into account the sheets data.

Comment: Hi, @Dean! I have tried the code above. It replaces my "Data Source" header with the worksheet name but it outputs where it came from correctly. There was a bit of a problem though. It ends at the 1st sheet and doesn't move on to the next sheets for some reason. What I did to fix it is not something I understand but I have added a +1 in the StartRow = lngLastDstRowNum part of the code and it outputted the correct sheet names. Would be nice if I could understand how that worked. Nevertheless, thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate the time and effort you have put into this :)

Comment: Oh yes, sure. You would need to offset your `StartRow` by 1, hence adding. This will prevent overlap from previous. I will edit my answer to show this.